# Unable to subscribe to Salesforce Platform Event with camel-salesforce-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: apache-camel, salesforce

I'm trying to subscribe to a Platform Event in Salesforce:

```
from("salesforce:event/Moodle__e?replayId=-1")
    .streamCaching()
    .process( exchange ->{
        PlatformEvent event = exchange.getIn().getBody(PlatformEvent.class);
        System.out.println("*********Receive Event : " + event.getEventData().toString());
   });
```

However receive the following error:

```
2020-05-21 14:23:35.061  WARN 3472 --- [ent@3cad68df-20] o.a.c.c.salesforce.SalesforceConsumer    : Error subscribing to event/Moodle__e: {httpCode=500}. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException - Error subscribing to event/Moodle__e: {httpCode=500}]

org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException: Error subscribing to event/Moodle__e: {httpCode=500}
        at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.streaming.SubscriptionHelper$7.onMessage(SubscriptionHelper.java:446) [camel-salesforce-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession$AbstractSessionChannel.notifyOnMessage(AbstractClientSession.java:583) [cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession$AbstractSessionChannel.notifyMessageListeners(AbstractClientSession.java:568) [cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.notifyListeners(AbstractClientSession.java:308) [cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.lambda$receive$4(AbstractClientSession.java:269) [cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.bayeux.Promise$2.succeed(Promise.java:103) ~[bayeux-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.common.AsyncFoldLeft$AbstractLoop.run(AsyncFoldLeft.java:199) ~[cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.common.AsyncFoldLeft.run(AsyncFoldLeft.java:93) ~[cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.extendIncoming(AbstractClientSession.java:103) [cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.common.AbstractClientSession.receive(AbstractClientSession.java:263) [cometd-java-common-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.failMessage(BayeuxClient.java:810) ~[cometd-java-client-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.messageFailure(BayeuxClient.java:806) ~[cometd-java-client-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient.messagesFailure(BayeuxClient.java:659) ~[cometd-java-client-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient$MessageTransportListener.onFailure(BayeuxClient.java:1266) ~[cometd-java-client-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport$2.onComplete(LongPollingTransport.java:255) ~[cometd-java-client-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:218) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:210) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:543) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:523) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:486) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:326) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseFields(HttpParser.java:1161) ~[jetty-http-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1534) ~[jetty-http-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:200) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:141) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:75) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:156) ~[jetty-client-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:543) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:398) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) ~[jetty-io-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) ~[jetty-util-9.4.27.v20200227.jar:9.4.27.v20200227]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: org.cometd.common.TransportException: {httpCode=500}
        at org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport$2.onComplete(LongPollingTransport.java:254) ~[cometd-java-client-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I have successfully tested this event with other client app. I also tris this suggested solution to turn off the Salesforce Mobile Notification but still got the same error:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55728/403unknown-client-error-when-connecting-to-streaming-api-push-topic/207824#207824

Has anyone successfully subscribed to Salesforce Platform Event or has encountered this error and know how to workaround? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different Salesforce API version, at least 37.0.

https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/salesforce-component.html#_query_parameters_45_parameters

You can specify the apiVersion as endpoint parameter.